# Use Async/Await in Node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to get this library https://github.com/bencevans/node-sonos running in an node 6.10 environment. Problem is that is build for a higher node version but I need it to be able to run on a 6.10 system. So I tried downgrading the package manually. The biggest feature which node 6.10 can not handle is async await keyword. I found the asyncawait package which seems to fix that to a certain extend but I can not figure out how to rewrite class methods with it:

```
class SonosListener extends EventEmitter{
async stopListener () {
    if (this._listening) {
      this._eventServer.close()
      this._listening = false

      let cancel = function (s) {
        return s.cancelAllSubscriptions()
      }
      var cancelAll = this._deviceSubscriptions.map(cancel)
      return Promise.all(cancelAll)
    } else {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { reject(new Error('Not listening')) })
    }
  }

}
```

How can I resolve this function using the asyncawait package in node 6.10?

Comment: This looks like a considerable job, and async/await code may not be easily translated to asyncawait API. I'd suggest to compile the package with Babel or use babel-node if this is not limited to a single package. Btw, sonos@0.x seems to be compatible with Node 6.

Comment: Wow thank you I completly missed that there is a branch for that.